# Flex/AS3: How to call an ActionScript function from within textFlow?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm working with a Flex 4 mxml file that uses a textFlow for RichEditableText as follows:

```
<s:RichEditableText>
    <s:textFlow>
        <s:TextFlow>
            <s:p>Here is your result: {myVariable}</s:p>
        </s:TextFlow>
    </s:textFlow>
</s:RichEditableText>
```

myVariable is returned from the middleTier, and equals character "a", "b", or "c". But since I need to display a message depending on what the character is, I want to call an actionscript function to decode myVariable. For example:

```
private function myFunction(myVariable):String {
  if (myVariable=="a") 
      myMsg = "You selected letter a";
  else if (myVariable=="b")
      myMsg = "You selected letter b";
  else
      myMsg = "You selected letter c";
  return myMsg;
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this, but I tried the following:

```
<s:RichEditableText>
    <s:textFlow>
        <s:TextFlow>
             <s:p>Here is your result: {myFunction(myVariable)}</s:p>
        </s:TextFlow>
    </s:textFlow>
</s:RichEditableText>
```

Although it compiled fine and ran, the result was -- nothing got displayed, not even the `Here is your result:` text.

Any idea how to achieve this? Alternatively, if it's not possible to call an actionscript function from inside the `<s:p> ... </s:p>`, then can this be achieved using an inline (sometimes called shorthand) if/then/else actionscript statement?

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Actually, the above code works fine. I determined the problem I was having is if the variable `myVariable` is not passed as an argument to myFunction(). I thought that since `myVariable` was declared as `[Bindable]` that it would always be available everywhere. However, the value of `myVariable` inside myFunction() is null unless it gets passed in as a parameter to myFunction().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add text dynamically.refer this link http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/10/09/dynamically-adding-paragraphs-to-a-spark-richtext-control-in-flex-4/

Comment: Another useful link: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7ff9.html